# configure ghc's default output file extension?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When I have a file `foo.hs` and run `ghc foo.hs`, it generates a binary file without an extension, `foo`. This is rather inconvenient for ignoring by `.gitignore`, so I'd like to know if there's a way to configure ghc so that it defaults to other extension (such as `.out`).

Of course, I could write simple shell script, basically

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ghc $1 -o "${1%.*}.out"
```

,but that'd be my "plan b".

Comment: One way would be to store the executables files in a separate directory by passing `-outputdir` option in ghc and adding that directory in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Ignore filenames that do *not* contain a dot?

Comment: Both @Sibi 's suggestion and @Bakuriu 's have good parts.`-outputdir` is nice because I can use the same option for all file. Ignoring filenames without dots seems to be a great alternative when there aren't many files that doesn't contain dot in their names and yet should be tracked (such as README).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is way too old but today I solved this problem myself by doing a `mv` command after compiling and it worked fine .

You can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ghc $1 # add whatever compiler options you want.

# stores the input name without extension 
# which is basically the outputname into a variable
I="${1%.*}"

# used v flag to see what really is going on.
mv $I $I.out -v
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to StackOverflow, but I don't see this as a useful suggestion. In fact it's quite a bit more awkward than just telling GHC to generate the `.out` file right away, which as the OP already wrote can be done with the `-o` flag.

Comment: @leftaroundabout the -o flag controls the the object's file extension not the executable's as I know but thanks for the suggestion I will try that .